# Detect rotation using iphone's sensors

Tags: iphone, rotation, accelerometer, sensors, gyroscope

I'm building an application that detects if the phone has rotated 360 degrees. This rotation will most likely be done in 35 seconds. How do I detect this accurately? I've read some articles about 'integration' and using the gyroscope for the short term and the accelerometer to compensate the gyroscope. What is the best way to achieve this, and, to start, how do I get the rotation values from the gyroscope?

I don't really understand the RotationMatrix from the multiplied by inverse'd CMAttitude. CMAttitude.yaw gives me different values even when I'm not using the phone. I have also seen the teapot example. My code goes about the same, except that I need to process the data from the RotationMatrix myself, since I'm not using OpenGL to do this for me.

Thanks in advance,
Hidde

Comment: Around what axis do you need to detect a 360 degree rotation?

Comment: Any axis. It's unknown how the phone is positioned

Comment: If not an axis in the real world, then what axis relative to the phone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking into the core motion API it seems your best bet is to monitor the rotation rate. Specifically through the [CMDeviceMotion](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreMotion/Reference/CMDeviceMotion_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CMDeviceMotion/rotationRate) interface which declares a rotationRate property with this discussion:

> A CMRotationRate structure contains data specifying the device’s rate
>   of rotation around three axes. The value of this property contains a
>   measurement of gyroscope data whose bias has been removed by Core
>   Motion algorithms. The identically name property of CMGyroData, on the
>   other hand, gives the raw data from the gyroscope. The structure type
>   is declared in CMGyroData.h.

You can monitor the events by declaring your interest through the [CMMotionManager method:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreMotion/Reference/CMMotionManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CMMotionManager/startDeviceMotionUpdatesUsingReferenceFrame%3atoQueue%3awithHandler%3a)

```
- (void)startDeviceMotionUpdatesUsingReferenceFrame:(CMAttitudeReferenceFrame)referenceFrame toQueue:(NSOperationQueue *)queue withHandler:(CMDeviceMotionHandler)handler
```

Then you'd need to do a bit of maths to work out the amount of time a rotation should occur at a given rate to constitute a full 360 degree rotation.

Comment: Thanks, I'll do some testing and calculating. You gave me the right set up.

Comment: So I've done some tests, but when I add up every rotation around the Y axis I get this number that is constantly changing even though I'm not moving the phone at all

Comment: There is a bias (an offset) in the rotation rates given by the gyroscope. This bias changes with time. The iPhone uses sophisticated algorithms (they call it "sensor fusion", but it's probably a Kalmann filter) to compensate for this bias by using the accelerometer. The attitude data you get in CMDeviceMotion is a result of this sensor fusion algorithm, whereas the rotations rates are unprocessed.

Comment: When using the attitude object I get better results. However, the value still shakes a bit, and when I move it fast it shakes a lot (too much). Is there any way to compensate this? And do I have still have to call multiplyByInverseOfAttitude on the received attitude object?